# How much difference will there be between 5/16" and 3/8" for a frameless shower door functionally

Tags: shower, glass, sliding-glass-door

I have a 3/8" glass shower (swing-type) door that I'm happy with, but now I'm looking for a frameless slider shower glass door, one side fixed. This is a 60" wide opening and 72" tall.

How much difference will there be between going a little thinner with 5/16" vs. 3/8" glass thickness in terms of functionally.

Answer (score 0):

> How much difference will there be between going a little thinner with
> 5/16" vs. 3/8" glass thickness in terms of functionally.

A 1/16th of an inch in the thickness of the glass will have No affect on functionality.

Is there a more specific concern you have?

Comment: I don't have a specific concern, just a general concern. Since I haven't tried it I wanted to check if anyone has strong opinions about it from experience. I would expect that at some point going down in thickness a door might flex more or just seem flimsy. I see 1/4" sliders too.

Comment: Thicker glass will definitely flex less. It will also feel much more solid but in addition weigh much more. The extra weight may or may not be an advantage that is next to impossible to evaluate unless being physically present.